# Keep "Activation Code" registry entry when user uninstalls application

Tags: inno-setup

During the installation of my application I ask the user to enter an Activation Code which will have been emailed to them.

If they uninstall the application I would like to keep the registry entry which holds the Activation Code (just in case they reinstall). Is there a flag I can set which will delete the entire Registry branch for my application apart from the entry I want to keep? Or alternatively a way to write it back in after uninstall finishes?

At the moment I have this:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\MyComp\MyApp"; Flags: uninsdeletekey
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\MyComp\MyApp"; ValueType: string; ValueName: "ActivationCode"; ValueData: "{code:GetSerialNumber|-}"; Check: SingleUserInstallation
```

Comment: Use flag `uninsdeletekeyifempty` for the main key. And for all other (except SerialNumber) use `uninsdeletevalue` flag. If you do not know the rest of keys it would be more difficult to achieve that goal.

Comment: The [`uninsdeletekey`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=registrysection&anchor=uninsdeletekey) that you used deletes the whole key when uninstalling.

Comment: Note that if you're using `PrivilegesRequired=admin` (which is the default) then you should not try to uninstall anything from HKCU in the first place.